# Google Apps Script - difference in behavior of function in library vs function in script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a library with function:

```
function isObject(value) {
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Object;
}
```

When I attach this lib to a script and run:

```
function myFunction() {
  let obj = {test: 1};
  let testObj1 = myLib.isObject(obj);
  Logger.log(testObj1)
}
```

I get "false"

When I run the function directly from a script:

```
Logger.log(isObject(obj))
```

I get "true"

I found out that the problem is with comparing:

```
value.constructor === Object
```

I ran both with logger:

```
function isObject(value) {
  Logger.log('---');
  Logger.log('value');
  Logger.log(value);
  Logger.log('typeof value');
  Logger.log(typeof value);
  Logger.log(typeof value === 'object');
  Logger.log('value.constructor');
  Logger.log(value.constructor);
  Logger.log(value.constructor === Object);
  return value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Object;
}
```

This is the output:

```
21:17:03    Uwaga   Rozpoczęto wykonywanie
21:17:02    Informacje  ---
21:17:02    Informacje  value
21:17:02    Informacje  {test=1.0}
21:17:02    Informacje  typeof value
21:17:02    Informacje  object
21:17:02    Informacje  true
21:17:02    Informacje  value.constructor
21:17:02    Informacje  function Object() { [native code] }
21:17:02    Informacje  false
21:17:02    Informacje  false
21:17:02    Informacje  ---
21:17:02    Informacje  value
21:17:02    Informacje  {test=1.0}
21:17:02    Informacje  typeof value
21:17:02    Informacje  object
21:17:02    Informacje  true
21:17:02    Informacje  value.constructor
21:17:02    Informacje  function Object() { [native code] }
21:17:02    Informacje  true
21:17:02    Informacje  true
21:17:03    Uwaga   Ukończono wykonywanie
```

Do you know what's the difference here or what's wrong?

**Library script Id**: 1vfY9qDHll-kheQ3a-zQQZjplCQNPukAiYrYT2jbBJ32NxDE56LJ0UhoP

**Link to GAS script**: https://script.google.com/d/1vfY9qDHll-kheQ3a-zQQZjplCQNPukAiYrYT2jbBJ32NxDE56LJ0UhoP/edit?usp=sharing

**Link to test script which is using the library**: https://script.google.com/d/1a8HF55t_DyN3iwNYjW7tGnfTiq-y0jOf2sqy5awipikbgQwb4cYQJpMl/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I tried replicating your code and it returns the same values. Why do you still need the `value.constructor === Object` if you are already checking it using typeof?

Comment: I check it because typeof Array is also "object". I attached library script Id, link to code and link to test script which is using the library.